# Launching lib\main.dart on SM A705FN in debug mode

Tags: java, gradle

I updated Flutter SDK to version 3.13 and encountered an issue. I created a new project, and when trying to run it, it takes an unusually long time, approximately an hour, and the application doesn't build.

When I run "flutter doctor," it reports everything as normal.

Here are the versions I'm using:

- Flutter 3.13
- Java 20
- Gradle 7.5
  I also tried using Gradle 8.3, but the issue persists.

I'm facing the problem where it doesn't build the application even after running the command:
"Launching lib\main.dart on SM A705FN in debug mode..."

Can you provide any assistance with this issue?